# SQL Select including Data type and Data values

Tags: mysql, sql, types, sqldatatypes

How could I select data from a table and include the data type with the values?
For example, I have table called EMPLOYEE with fname, lastname, phone, etc.
If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
```

I get all the columns. If I do:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEE'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

I get all the column names and their data types.

I need to combine these two so I have the values displayed along with the data type.

I'm new to SQL but I have searched on the web some and tried various JOIN and UNION statements, but I could just be entering them wrong.

Comment: It would be easier to combine the results of both queries in your `while` loop. You do not *have to* do all you need with SQL.

Comment: This is an odd requirement. Why do you need both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `SELECT EMPLOYEE.COL1, INFO.DATA_TYPE FROM EMPLOYEE, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS INFO WHERE INFO.TABLE_NAME='EMPLOYEE' AND COLUMN_NAME='COL1'`
But to select more fields, you'd have to add another instance of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS again with a different alias.

But you should not do this for many reasons.

Technically: CROSS JOIN (the tables in FROM listed simply with a comma) is much strain on the database server. `FROM T1, T2` pairs up all rows of T1 with all rows of T2 and examines the result rows. If T1 has n rows and T2 has m then the result has n*m rows.

Logically 1: You should not need this information to be returned. When you enter a query (a SELECT) the the returned schema is known; the query determines what datatypes the result columns are.
Logically 2: Since every row has the same datatypes in the columns, you do not need the type information to be returned in every row. E.g. your example returning data of 1000 employees would unnecessarily transfer on **every line** that the AGE field is INTEGER, the NAME is VARCHAR and so on...

If you somehow would not know the schema of the result (e.g. because of generated queries or the like) then the above solution would not help you.

Comment: Lewyx, thanks this gets me closer to what I need. 
This is for a class project where I have created a data-grid view. I have a text box where a user can input an SQL statement and have the results show up in the grid. Now what I need is to take that same SQL statement and select the same columns and show the data types. I  am trying to avoid having to parse all of the text from the box.
Ideally I would like to just have a view that shows the column names selected and their data type in addition to the view that shows the results. If all else fails I am willing to display each data type.

Comment: I see. Note that in real-world applications it is imperative (for security reasons) not to allow users to directly interact with SQL statement. I take this is for the purpose of a class-project so being OK. -- The SQL connector that your application uses most probably gets a complete description of the columns' datatypes and depending on what language/interface you use, you might be able to extract that information. Reading the datatypes is still not something for SQL to do. ;) We may hint you further if you specify which components you use for DB access.