# How to get all data along with its datatype in a single query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

let there is a table ***user(user_id int,user_name varchar)***

I want to get all data along with its datatype in a single query in mysql.

```
select * from user;
describe user;
```

but these are two different query. I want the result in a single query.I want to get the result in php so that i can convert in a json i.e. json_encode;

Actually I want to get the result in the following format... only 1 row is available

```
[
 {"attr_name":"user_id","value","5","attr-type":"int"},
 {"attr_name":"user_name","value","6","attr-type":"varchar"}
]
```

Comment: First question: **What have you tried?**

Comment: I want to send the data with type as well

Comment: PHP code. MySQL code. Something. Anything. There's nothing here, and this site focuses on helping people actively trying to solve problems. You're at the early stage, you've identified your objective. The next step is to write some code that takes a shot at solving it.

Comment: Take a closer look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093551/how-to-return-field-type-from-mysql-query) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114243/sql-select-including-data-type-and-data-values

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysqli - then after running doing a `mysqli_prepare` with your select * statement, you can call

```
$result = $stmt->result_metadata();
```

To get a description of each field.
If using PDO - use `getColumnMeta` in something like

```
$select = $DB->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
```